# Which SharePoint Conference 2011 - Europe or USA?

Tags: community

If you could go to one SharePoint conference in 2011 in Europe or USA, which would it be?

Just trying to plan the year :)

Comment: Community wiki! :)

Comment: @James, Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't done any conferences in the states yet myself, but the European Best Practices conference in London was fantastic last year, and I'll be heading this year too.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't in your countries but I'm going to try and go to this Australian one:

http://www.sharepointconference.com.au